# Sharing a SD card partition between Linux and Windows

Tags: usb, sd-card, partitioning

I've a SD card formatted (with multiple partitions) and one of them is FAT32 which is mounted in Linux. This FAT32 partition will be shown as USB Drive in Windows and i'will have to mount it in Linux in order to see its contents.

While i was able to share and view this partition contents in Linux and windows, it seems that any changes (like creating a new file/modifications to an existing file) done in Linux are reflecting in Windows unless i unmount and mount it again. It's true the other way as well.

I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue..

Answer (score 1):

Remember that an SD card or USB drive / stick will be accessed at block level. The interface provides no knowledge of the directory structure or FAT contents that the host OS is using. If two devices have simultaneous access to a block-level device, they each assume that they have full control of the device and cache structures for performance. Therefore any changes one host OS makes to the contents of the storage media are not known to the other host OS.

This is the very reason that newer Android devices implement the MTP protocol instead of USB MSC to allow a host access to their media. MTP allows the Android OS to maintain control of the file system structures while exposing its contents to the host.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is there any other option other than MTP protocol?

Comment: The only other similar device class that I'm familiar with is PTP used by cameras for photo transfer.